# Docker container exits after custom entrypoint and original entrypoint execution

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pimcore

I'm encountering an issue with my Docker setup where the container exits unexpectedly after executing a custom entrypoint script and the original entrypoint provided by the base image.
**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM pimcore/pimcore:php8.2-latest

ENV PATH="./vendor/bin:${PATH}" \
    NGINX_SERVER_NAME="prod" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS="0" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES="6000" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION="128" \
    PHP_FPM_PM_MAX_CHILDREN=30 \
    PHP_FPM_PM_START_SERVERS=15 \
    PHP_FPM_PM_MIN_SPARE_SERVERS=15 \
    PHP_FPM_PM_MAX_SPARE_SERVERS=25 \
    PHP_FPM_PM_MAX_REQUESTS=500 
    # PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=512M

COPY ./ /var/www/html
COPY ../docker/php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN find /var/www/html -print | xargs --max-args=1 --max-procs=10000 -i chown -R 33:33 "{}" | true

COPY pimcore/configure_memory.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/configure_memory.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/configure_memory.sh", "/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

**configure_memory.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Configuring memory..."

# Perform any additional checks or configurations here
if [ "$(awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo)" -ge 16000000 ]; then
    echo "Setting memory_limit to 512M"
    echo "memory_limit = 512M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20-pimcore.ini
    #modify ENV variables
else
    echo "Setting memory_limit to 256M"
    echo "memory_limit = 256M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20-pimcore.ini
     #modify ENV variables
fi

echo "Executing the original command: $@"

# Execute the CMD of the Docker image
exec "$@"
```

The container exits with code 0 after executing both the custom entrypoint script (**`configure_memory.sh`**) and the original entrypoint (**`docker-php-entrypoint`**).

Please note that I don't want to override the original image CMD and ENTRYPOINT. I want to first just execute the custom **`configure_memory.sh`** script at runtime to properly assign the **`memory_limit`** and the the original image CMD and ENTRYPOINT to continue. The reason for this is that I use the same image on two different app services—one with 16GB of memory and the other with 3.5GB. I need to dynamically configure the **`memory_limit`** based on the available memory during runtime.

Is there a better way to configure the **`memory`*`limit`****, max_*children( and the other variables) for this scenario, or am I on the right track with the current approach?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ENTRYPOINT` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) notes

> If `CMD` is defined from the base image, setting `ENTRYPOINT` will reset `CMD` to an empty value. In this scenario, `CMD` must be defined in the current image to have a value.

You need to find the Dockerfile for the base image, or `docker inspect` it to find its entrypoint.  For this image, its [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/pimcore/pimcore) points at a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pimcore/docker) that contains a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pimcore/docker/blob/3.x/Dockerfile).  The `pimcore_php_default` stage ends with

```bash
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

and you need to repeat this in your own Dockerfile.  (Note that stage does not seem to obviously declare an `ENTRYPOINT`.)